# Join tables with separate rows [Query]

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Ive looked around online the past 2 hours to solve my issue, i have 2 tables with the same user. i would like to join both tables whilst not combining them into the same row.

### I have tried multiple ways of joining tables.

Example:

Table 1:

```
ID| User  | item
1 | Peter | Apple
2 | Peter | Grape
3 | John  | Apple
4 | Smith | Lemon
```

Table 2:

```
ID| User  | Cars
1 | Smith | Mazda
2 | Peter | BMW
3 | Jamie | Apple
4 | Peter | Honda
```

Im trying to make a query that would give show me all the items a person owns, here is how id like the query result to return.

Query Result im trying to get:

```
ID| User  | Belongings
1 | Peter | Honda
2 | Peter | BMX
3 | Peter | Apple
4 | Peter | Grape
```

Comment: id seems meaningless in the context of this result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select id, user, item
from table1 t1
where user = 'Peter'
union all
select id, user, item
from table2 t2
where user = 'Peter';
```

If you want to reassign the id:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, user, item
from ((select id, user, item
       from table1 t1
       where user = 'Peter'
      ) union all
      (select id, user, item
       from table2 t2
       where user = 'Peter'
      )
     ) p cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
```